# Use requests-html to test Flask app without starting server

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, wsgi, werkzeug

I've been using the Flask `test_client` object to test my web applications. I used [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the HTML output of some of these calls.

Now I wanted to try [requests-html](http://requests-html.kennethreitz.org/) instead, but I cannot figure out how to make it work with the Flask test client. The examples all use the [request package](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to get the response, but the Werkzeug test client does not make an actual HTTP call. From what I can tell, it sets up the environment and just calls the handler method.

Is there a way to make this work without having to have the actual service running?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[requests-wsgi-adapter](https://pypi.org/project/requests-wsgi-adapter/) provides an adapter to mount a WSGI callable at a URL. You use [`session.mount()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/advanced/#id15) to mount adapters, so for [requests-html](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) you'd use `HTMLSession` instead and mount to that.

```
$ pip install flask requests-wsgi-adapter requests-html
```

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from wsgiadapter import WSGIAdapter

s = HTMLSession()
s.mount("http://test", WSGIAdapter(app))
```

```py
r = s.get("http://test/")
assert r.html.find("p")[0].text == "Hello, World!"
```

The downside of using requests is that you have to add `"http://test/"` before every URL you want to make a request to. The Flask test client doesn't require this.

---

Instead of using requests and requests-html, you could also tell the Flask test client to return a Response that does the BeautifulSoup parsing for you. After a quick look at requests-html, I still prefer the direct Flask test client and BeautifulSoup API.

```
$ pip install flask beautifulsoup4 lxml
```

```py
from flask.wrappers import Response
from werkzeug.utils import cached_property

class HTMLResponse(Response):
    @cached_property
    def html(self):
        return BeautifulSoup(self.get_data(), "lxml")

app.response_class = HTMLResponse
c = app.test_client()
```

```py
r = c.get("/")
assert r.html.p.text == "Hello, World!"
```

---

You should also consider using [HTTPX](https://www.python-httpx.org/) instead of requests. It's a modern, well maintained HTTP client library that shares many API similarities with requests. It also has great features like async, HTTP/2, and built-in ability to [call WSGI applications directly](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#client-instances).

```
$ pip install flask httpx
```

```py
c = httpx.Client(app=app, base_url="http://test")
```

```py
with c:
    r = c.get("/")
    html = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    assert html.p.text == "Hello, World!"
```